# Programmatically factorize selected columns in data frame, the tidy way?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

Here is a simplified example:

```
library(tidyverse)

frame <- tribble(
  ~a, ~b, ~c,
   1,  1,  2,
   5,  4,  7,
   2,  3,  4, 
   3,  1,  6
)

key <- tribble(
  ~col, ~name, ~type, ~labels,
     1,   "a",   "f",     c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five"),
     2,   "b",   "f",     c("uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro"),
     3,   "c",   "f",     1:7
)
```

Is there an elegant way of programmatically sweeping across the columns in `frame` and applying the specific factor class, based on the parameters in `key`? The expected result would be:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
       a      b      c
  <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
1    one    uno      2
2   five cuatro      7
3    two   tres      4
4  three    uno      6
```

The best solution I have so far is using `purrr`'s `map2()` but with assignment that is IMO not the most elegant:

```
frame[key$col] <- map2(key$col, key$labels, 
        function(x, y) factor(frame[[x]], levels = 1:length(y), labels = y))
```

Does anyone have a more tidy solution? Note that my original data frame has hundreds of columns and I need to re-factor with different levels/labels a majority of them, so the process has to be automated.

Comment: Hadley has a `forcats` package, if that sounds interesting.

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a look and it is quite nice - however it does not directly provide functions to manipulate data frames the way I would like...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm interested to see what other solutions are proposed for this. My only suggestion is to change the proposed solution slightly so it is clearer that `frame` is going to be modified in some way rather than leaving it in the body of the function used by `map2`.

For example, pass `frame` as an additional argument in the call to `map2`:

```
frame[key$col] <- map2(key$col, key$labels, 
                       function(x, y, z) factor(z[[x]], levels = 1:length(y), labels = y), 
                       frame)
```

Or do the same thing using the pipe operator `%>%`:

```
frame[key$col] <- frame %>%
  { map2(key$col, key$labels, 
         function(x, y, z) factor(z[[x]], levels = 1:length(y), labels = y), .) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll mark your post as answered, it seems this is the optimal approach so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. I am not sure how "elegant" it is. Hopefully, someone can improve on that.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))

frame <- tribble(
  ~a, ~b, ~c,
  1,  1,  2,
  5,  4,  7,
  2,  3,  4, 
  3,  1,  6
)

key <- tribble(
  ~col, ~name, ~type, ~labels,
  1,   "a",   "f",     c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five"),
  2,   "b",   "f",     c("uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro"),
  3,   "c",   "f",     1:7
)

colnames(frame) %>% 
  map(~ {
    factor(pull(frame, .x),
           levels = 1:length(pluck(key[key$name == .x, "labels"], 1, 1)),
           labels = pluck(key[key$name == .x, "labels"], 1, 1))
  }) %>% 
  set_names(colnames(frame)) %>% 
  as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>        a      b      c
#>   <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
#> 1    one    uno      2
#> 2   five cuatro      7
#> 3    two   tres      4
#> 4  three    uno      6
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answer satisfies your requirements of being tidy as it uses a plain old for-loop. But it does the job and in my opinion is easy to read/understand as well as reasonably fast.

```
library(tidyverse)
frame <- tribble(
 ~a, ~b, ~c,
 1,  1,  2,
 5,  4,  7,
 2,  3,  4, 
 3,  1,  6
)

key <- tribble(
 ~col, ~name, ~type, ~labels,
 1,   "a",   "f",     c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five"),
 2,   "b",   "f",     c("uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro"),
 3,   "c",   "f",     1:7
)

for (i in 1:nrow(key)) {
 var <- key$name[[i]]
 x <- frame[[var]]
 labs <- key$labels[[i]]
 lvls <- 1:max(length(x), length(labs)) # make sure to have the right lengths

 frame <- frame %>% mutate(!! var := factor(x, levels = lvls, labels = labs))
}

frame
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>        a      b      c
#>   <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
#> 1    one    uno      2
#> 2   five cuatro      7
#> 3    two   tres      4
#> 4  three    uno      6
```

The typical tidy-approach would be to reshape the data to have all variables in one column, then apply a function to that column, and finally reshaping it to the original format. However, factors don't really like that, thus we need to use other means. Are factors even considered tidy?

## Edit

Regarding my assumption that the for-loop would be similar to the `map2`-function, I was wrong.

Here are some benchmarks:

```
library(microbenchmark)

frame1 <- frame
frame2 <- frame

microbenchmark(
 map2 = {
  frame1[key$col] <- map2(key$col, key$labels, 
                          function(x, y) factor(frame[[x]], 
                                                levels = 1:max(frame[[x]],
                                                               length(y)), 
                                                labels = y))
 },
 forloop = {
  for (i in 1:nrow(key)) {
   var <- key$name[[i]]
   x <- frame2[[var]]
   labs <- key$labels[[i]]
   lvls <- 1:max(length(x), length(labs))
   frame2 <- frame2 %>% mutate(!! var := factor(x, levels = lvls, labels = labs))
  }
 }
)

# Unit: microseconds
# expr         min         lq       mean    median         uq       max neval cld
# map2      375.53   416.5805   514.3126   450.825   484.2175  3601.636   100  a 
# forloop 11407.80 12110.0090 12816.6606 12564.176 13425.6840 16632.682   100   b
```

Comment: Thanks @David for the very elaborate answer! It seems though that the original solution I proposed is quite a bit faster...

Answer (score 0):

For this question, you can use a base R code:

```
(A=`names<-`(data.frame(mapply(function(x,y)x[y],key$labels,frame)),key$name))
      a      b c
1   one    uno 2
2  five cuatro 7
3   two   tres 4
4 three    uno 6

 sapply(A,class)
   a        b        c 
"factor" "factor" "factor"
```